# How to Speed up C# Form full text search from TextBox

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, buffer, textchanged

I need to achieve similar to `TextChanged` functionality of `TextBox` field in C# Windows Forms application.
In my case `TextChanged` Event collects data based on `TextBox.Text` and displays them in tree.
As collecting and displaying too much data in my case is time consuming, I'm experiencing slow responses caused by unwanted redraws in GUI.
This is of course by design of `TextChanged` event as it buffers later key-presses and run `TextChanged` for each letter. I need to achieve that all buffered `TextChanged` events are skipped resulting only last is executed. In fact as I type i need to change this

```
l, lo, lon, long, longn, longna, longnam, longname
```

to this:

```
l, longname
```

Comment: Have you thought about only applying the search after either a pause in keystrokes or only in response to a certain keystroke. Another thought would be like Padawan Learner is saying and ignoring intermediaries while the search is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to periodically check for changes to your TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to slow it down, do the processing in a timer tick handler, but start with the timer disabled. On a text change, disable the timer, and then enable it. Make sure the timer is a one-shot timer (not-repeating). This means that processing will occur no sooner than the timer interval after the text changes, and that new text changes cancel any previous changes that were set to occur. This is what you want. As the user types, the processing will be delayed again and again until the user pauses typing.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised it was soo simple...

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doSearch();
    timer1.Stop();
}
```